# How to generate installshield ism file with installshield command

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

we want to generate the msi package in an automatically way, and we try to use installshield.

now we try to generate ism file with xml based first and then use `iscmdbld.exe` to generate the msi package....there is limited documentation about how to generate the ism file... and we have no idea about ism file currently.

we want to pass the arguments such as files path, shortcut information, registry key information to the powershell command and then generate the ism file... is it possible ?

Comment: Too broad for a SO question, but it sounds like you're looking for the [InstallShield Automation Interface](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield23helplib/installshield23helplib.htm#helplibrary/IHelpAutomation.htm), which can be invoked from any COM compatible language (including PowerShell).

Comment: thank you for your comment, i read this article before, and I have one issues about the automation interface... does the interfaces support 64-bit Operation system ?

Comment: It runs on a 64 bit OS, but only in a 32 bit process.

Comment: The automation inteface is really lacking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible but a lot of effort and likely misguided.  Anyone who truely needs this (I did once and only once in 20 years.)  would have gone very far down the traditional routes until they hit a wall and at that point they knew enough about the technology to know how to do all this.

InstallShield does have the Automation Interface but last time I looked there's A LOT it can't do.   So you'll be saving the ISM in binary format and using MSI apis to manipulate alot of this information.

Look me up if you want to talk about this for an hour on the house.